# A nth degree polynomial has nth roots then what happens when n is fractional rather than a whole number?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I got stumbled when I encountered a problem in Halliday/Resnick 10th ed.
It stated that water is poured into a container that has got a small leak.The mass of water given as function of time :
$$m(t) = 5t^{0.8} - 3 t + 20$$ unit  with $t\geq 20$ seconds
Then at what time water is greatest in the container

I first approached the problem by finding a derivative w.r.t $t$

which is:   $m'(t)=4 t^{-0.2}-3$

now setting it to $0$ we get a polynomial: $4t^{-.02} -3 = 0$
...lo here I got stumbled
wolframalpha gave answer = $4.21399$ but..

So here are two question:
1.)Thread title
2.)How to find the root in this case(instead of brute-forcing/plug-chug)?

Comment: $4t^{-1/5}=3$ is equivalent to $t=(4/3)^5=4.214$. [Or to be more pedantic, that is the only real solution.]

Comment: If the exponents are not integers it is not a polynomial but a power equation. However as almagest shows, you can sometimes substitute or switch field and it may become a polynomial.

Comment: Hint:  Since the derivative is strictly negative in the region you care about, we know the function is monotonically decreasing.

Comment: $t^{-0.02}$ in your equation should probably be $t^{-0.2}$, I tried editing it for you, but seemed to be a conflict.

Comment: @mathreadler :interesting I never knew about that...can you provide a link/pointer to a source/references .                                                                  Ok lets say that the given example example is the power equation but again the question arises say the exponents are in fraction(though the statement is not polynomial according to the definition)..then how will you approach the problem?

Comment: If it is a fraction of integers you can do a sequence of operations of integer powers and division to turn it into a polynomial. In this case, divide by $t^{-1/5}$ and then raise to 5 will give $t$ exponent 1 on the other side o the equation.

Answer (score 1):

As there seems to be some confusion about what a polynomial is...
An example of a **polynomial** (of degree $N$) in $x$ is $$p(x) = \sum_{k=0}^N c_kx^k$$
So a polynomial has only terms with **positive integer exponents**, and always a largest one, in this case $N$. If it does not have a largest exponent it is instead called a **power series**
$$f(x) = \sum_0^\infty c_kx^k$$
Power series still have positive integer exponents. A famous kind of power series are the **Taylor series** and **Maclaurin series** which are used a lot in calculus. Power series can be approximated by polynomials for example by skipping all the terms involving exponents above some $k$ value.

You can also say that your polynomial is not in $x$ but in a function. Some famous kinds of such polynomials are **trigonometric polynomials**, for example:

$$(\sin(x))^2 + 2\sin(x) + 1$$

This time the polynomial is not in $x$ but in $\sin(x)$. Then even more advanced things can be made, but a basic requirement is that it needs to be integers in the exponent of the field we are working with. This way polynomials will be defined for many mathematical objects, as only multiplication and addition need to be defined.